# How to feed FFMPEG AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE audio data to AudioQueue

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, audioqueue, audio-player

I am using FFMPEG in combination with [FFmpegAudioPlayer](https://github.com/alb423/FFmpegAudioPlayer) to do live streaming. The issue I am having is that, while the audio can be decoded and played, there's a constant clicking/screeching noise in the audio that isn't present when streaming the same source by other applications. So I am guess the issue arise due to how I process the FFMPEG `AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE` audio data before handing it to AudioQueue:

```
audioFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM;            
audioFormat.mFormatFlags = kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;//kAudioFormatFlagIsBigEndian|kAudioFormatFlagIsAlignedHigh;
audioFormat.mSampleRate = pAudioCodecCtx->sample_rate;
audioFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 8*av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = pAudioCodecCtx->channels;
audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame = pAudioCodecCtx->channels * av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
audioFormat.mBytesPerPacket= pAudioCodecCtx->channels * av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);
audioFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
audioFormat.mReserved = 0;

pSwrCtx = swr_alloc_set_opts(pSwrCtx,
                                             1,//pAudioCodecCtx->channel_layout,
                                             AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16,
                                             pAudioCodecCtx->sample_rate,
                                             1,//pAudioCodecCtx->channel_layout,
                                             AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16,
                                             pAudioCodecCtx->sample_rate,
                                             0,
                                             0);
outCount = swr_convert(pSwrCtx,
                                             (uint8_t **)(&pOut),
                                             in_samples,
                                             (const uint8_t **)pAVFrame1->extended_data,
                                             in_samples);
```

Please also note that I've tried many different parameters for `swr_alloc_set_opts`, but either the audio became unrecognizable or the noise persisted.

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4509828/audio_issue_20141022.mp3)'s a sample of the audio with clicking sound, if it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out the noise isn't a problem in decoding the audio stream, but a problem in the camera device that feed the audio stream to our app.

The noise is quite inaudible when connected to the Android app, caused us to miss it when testing Android app and thought it's a problem with how our iOS app handles audio rather than something that's wrong with the device.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly, but s16be is integer (16bit) whereas kAudioFormatLinearPCM is float (32bit).

If I were in your shoes, I'll just use s16be and kAudioFormatLinearPCM format which means fixing `AudioCodecCtx->channels * av_get_bytes_per_sample(AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16)` and others.
Then insert PCM format conversion step between ffmpeg -> iOS data flow.

This post looks like very helpful: [iOS Core Audio : Converting between kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical and kAudioFormatFlagsAudioUnitCanonical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478003/ios-core-audio-converting-between-kaudioformatflagscanonical-and-kaudioformatf)