# Core Audio Error Code "-10876"

Tags: core-audio, error-code

A lengthy google search does not tell me what this error code gets.  I get this after calling `AudioUnitRender()` on my remoteIO audio unit running on iphone.  I cannot find this error code in the Core Audio documentation either.

Comment: Show your audio unit callback code.  The error might be there.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS devices, this error (no connection) is reported be caused by an incompatible or not enabled AVAudioSession configuration; or maybe by trying to use an audio format (sample rate, bytes, endianess, etc.) incompatible with the device.  It might also be caused by trying to use a bogus buffer list or number of samples in the audio unit callback. Check the buffer list parameter, and all the earlier audio setup error return values.

Comment: It makes sense that it would be AVAudioSession.  I was attempting to modernize my code by replacing the deprecated AudioSession* Core Audio C calls with the new AVAudioSession objective C class.  However, I found no analog to AudioSessionInitialize in the AudioSession class.  If not the Session it could also be that I'm using AudioFormatFlagsCanonical which has been deprecated but I can't find any document online about what to replace that with.

Comment: Perhaps this post might also include some useful information:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478003/ios-core-audio-converting-between-kaudioformatflagscanonical-and-kaudioformatf